# Should I Save preprocessed image data to Disk?

Tags: deep-learning

I am taking a image classify competition. I've got nearly 50000 training data with 80 different classes. I have done some testing with some pretrained model like Vgg or Resnet, both works fine but not good enough, with a training acc almost to 1 and validation acc 0.85(overfitting). I think the bottleneck is with the data, not the model, so I come up with image augmentation.

Now I'm confused that should I save the transformed image to disk or just apply a random transform for every batch of every epoch. I am now practicing the later one and things are not improved so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving or not preprocessed data is above all a matter of time and a spoonful of repeatability in case you have any randomness in your preprocess.

If it's not time consuming, doing it on the fly should be the simpler approach. If on the other hand your preprocess is heavy (for instance when training only the last few layers and thus using intermediate layer outputs), it should be more useful to dump this results to disk so that you don't need to compute all the initial layers every time.

In other words, it's not much of a technical question and *dumping data or not should not interfere in your results*, rather it is simply a matter of convenience.